# turn a text file with 2 columns into Perl hash

Tags: perl, text, hash

Following is my INPUT Text File

```
StudentName                                       Address
Boris                                             Vietnam
Henry                                             Ukrine
Sarah                                             Road/47
                                                  Turkey
John                                              NewsLand 
                                                  now local
Boris                                             now local
Karen                                             4th/floor
                                                  WestHam/Apartments
                                                  Culverdown/Street
                                                  WestHam
                                                  UK
```

To convert the above into hash I have tried following (Ofcourse it doesnot work at all)

```
use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper;

my $out1 = "Sample.txt"; my %hash;


open FILE1, "<", $out1 or die "$!\n"; 
while ( <FILE1> ) { 
  chomp $_; 
  my ( $name, $address ) = split '\t', $_; 
  $hash{$name} = [$address];
  push @{ $hash{$name} }, $_; 
}

close FILE1;

print "ResultHash".Dumper(\%hash);
```

Can some one please suggest how to convert the above text file to hash .left columns would be keys right one would be columns. 
Note: I have all the unique key values with me from the register so I can use them as keys aswell. then i need to convert these 2 columns to values.one will be just studentname scalar and other will be address as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem you've got is your `while` loop iterates based on line feeds. On the first line - you have a student name, but the next line you don't.

So I'd suggest that what you want to do is instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %addresses;
my $current_student_name;

my $header_line = <>;

while (<>) {
    my $address_line;
    if (m/^\w/) {
        ( $current_student_name, $address_line ) = m/^(\w+)\s*(.*)/;
    }
    else {
        ($address_line) = m/^\s*(.*)/;
    }
    push( @{ $addresses{$current_student_name} }, $address_line );
}

print Dumper \%addresses;
```

Comment: Hi Sobrique, what is $header_line = <>; ? do you want me to put the file handle inside while condition?

Comment: Yes, if you like. But that is the magic file handle, which either reads STDIN or files specified on command line. But a normal one should work just the same.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know this before. Thank you. I passed my input text file name in command prompt and your program worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem here is correctly skipping the repeating names. One possible approach:

```
my $name;
while ( <FILE1> ) { 
  chomp; 
  my @row = split /\s+/, $_, 2;
  next if $row[0] eq 'StudentName';
  $name = $row[0] unless $row[0] eq '';
  push @{ $hash{$name} }, $row[1];
}
```

Here I used three-param form of `split` to limit the number of chunks, skipped `StudentName` row with `next`, filled `$name` only if the row begins with a non-whitespace symbol.

Note that due to autovivification you don't have to pre-create lists for each particular record - pushing will create the corresponding data structure automatically.

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you very much . I had written a long program using regex for this as i had problems limiting the number of chunks.....

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, this may be a solution.

```
my $prev_name;
while ( <FILE1> ) { 
    chomp $_; 
    my ( $name, $address ) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;
    $hash{$prev_name = $name} ||= [] if $name;
    push($hash{$name || $prev_name}, $address);
}
```

Comment: Opps. Spitting must be fail but it's easy to fix.